# React Hooks, variable reinitialized on rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, rerender, react-three-fiber

I am trying to keep data of a non-usestate variable on a rerender

I have a main component, which has a sub-component.

The sub-component contain a state and return a **Cube**.
It also contain **useFrame()**, that do an action on every frame.

I use it to do a rotation on the cube based on a **direction** variable (direction change every 3secs).
I also have another viariable, **time** that is incremented by the **delta** on each frame.

Problem is, when I **Click** the Cube, the sub-component is rerendered (normal), but I loose **time** and **direction** value in the process, they are reinitialized.

Is there a way to not loose the datas ? To not reinitialize them ?
I thought **useEffect** could do the trick, but I can't place it in **useFrame** (or **useFrame** in **useEffect**).
Tried **useMemo** also, which failed, it doesn't keep the updated value, but I'm not quite sure to use it well ? Is it possible to update, based on his own change ?

Made a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/cube-rotation-sdfv8?file=/src/App.js:290-300

In this example, I could use setInterval, but that's not my point here, this is just an example.
I'd like to use **useFrame** to move object for example, doing some "Go there, then comeback".

Using state/setState would also work, but I'd loose enormous performance, as it is done 60 times/s.
And I could have many objects.

Comment: If you want to preserve values between renders but not store them in state, you could store them in a ref

Comment: What @Jayce444 said (you should turn that into an answer!). To help explain why that's a good idea, refs (as in `useRef`) are specifically designed to be used as mutable variables in React components. The gotcha is that you have to read/write to the `ref.current` property, but doing so does not incur the render overhead of `useState`, and React will remember your values.

Comment: @Jayce444 ohh, didn't know useRef could be used for variable, thought it was only for Dom stuff.

And it works like a charm !
Made a new [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cube-rotation-forked-v7pie?file=/src/App.js) with your answer.

Is there a way to put your comment as correct answer ? That's my first post, dunno how stackotherflow works yet ^^'